# None of the specified endpoints were reachable

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

There is intermittent issue in rabbitmq while publishing message from .net application. It is creating lots of noise in the system. 
I have tried googling but could not found root cause of an issue.

Here is the error I can see in application log,

```
None of the specified endpoints were reachable
Endpoints attempted:
------------------------------------------------
endpoint=amqp-0-9://localhost:5672, attempts=1
System.TimeoutException: Connection to amqp-0-9://localhost:5672 timed out
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler_0_9.Connect(TcpClient socket, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Int32 timeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler_0_9..ctor(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, ObtainSocket socketFactory, Int32 timeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.v0_9_1.ProtocolBase.CreateFrameHandler(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, ObtainSocket socketFactory, Int32 timeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.FollowRedirectChain(Int32 maxRedirects, IDictionary`2 connectionAttempts, IDictionary`2 connectionErrors, AmqpTcpEndpoint[]& mostRecentKnownHosts, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint)
================================================
Stack trace:
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(Int32 maxRedirects)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()
```

Comment: are you sure the broker is running?  what user name and password are you using?

Comment: Yes, the broker is running fine. I have other four applications running on my server, the problem is with only one application.

Comment: do you have a problem only with "remote" application? in this case could be a firewall problem

Comment: @Gas RabbitMQ and applications are on the same machine. So there should not be a firewall problem.
Actually, the same is working fine right now, the issue is intermittent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by making RabbitMQ Connection object singleton to make sure reuse connection instead of making new connection everytime.

Comment: Recommended approach is to have one connection per process and on channel per thread